# Wrong day paramenter in new Date()?

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain me, why I get 12 Februray when running the code below?

I saw the days are from 1 to 31, only the months starts with 0

```
var d = new Date(2100,1,13)
> d
Fri, 12 Feb 2100 23:00:00 GMT
```

**EDIT:**

And why this time?? `23:00:00` it should be `00:00:00`

Comment: Oh, looks like you got Feb 12!  Rewrite your question.  By the way - I get Feb 13, not Feb 12.

Comment: I get Feb 13 2100 00:00:00 ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Ua2cA/))

Comment: Oh, look at the time.  You get Feb 13 -1hr.  What's your timezone?

Comment: What time zone is your computer set to? ( @LeeKowalkowski — Beat me to it :) )

Comment: OMG it is too strange, i'm getting 12 Feb testing this instruction on NODE.js

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski. It doesn't matter.

Comment: See: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference for more about Javascript and Timezones

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your locale timezone is interfering.  Try: `new Date(Date.UTC(2100,1,13))`.

Comment: Date.UTC() creates a date in UTC time (UTC is the new GMT), not in your local time.  You could output the time locally instead if you prefer, using the toLocale functions `.toLocaleString()` `.toLocaleDateString()` and `toLocaleTimeString()`.

Comment: Not working it show invalid date. Friday, Feb 12, 2100

Answer (score 3):

You are setting 13 Feb 2100 CET and getting output in GMT.

Comment: how can i adjust it in JS code? or how could i set it properly?

Answer (score 1):

The output is based on the GMT zone and not as per your time zone. Adjust your system time to proper time zone, you should be getting correct output. Hope that helps.